# RHQ Agent does not install

Tags: jboss, rhq

I configured the rhq-agent.bat. When I try to run it. It has the followings errors:

```
2015-06-25 14:51:24,891 ERROR [RHQ Server Polling Thread] (enterprise.communications.command.client.JBossRemotingRemoteCommunicator)- {JBossRemotingRemoteCommunicator.init-callback-failed}The initialize callback has failed. It will be tried again. Cause: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException:Can not connect http client invoker after 1 attempt(s) -> java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out: connect. Cause: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker after 1 attempt(s)

2015-06-25 14:51:42,987 ERROR [main] (org.rhq.enterprise.agent.AgentMain)- {AgentMain.plugin-update-failure}Failed to update the plugins.. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The sender object is currently not sending commands now. Command not sent: [Command: type=[remotepojo]; cmd-in-response=[false]; config=[{rhq.send-throttle=true}]; params=[{invocation=NameBasedInvocation[getLatestPlugins], targetInterfaceName=org.rhq.core.clientapi.server.core.CoreServerService}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it myself the problem was the security token. I modified those fields in the registry vierwer (Windows). When I restarted the agent it worked.